# ShoreTel 230 phone calls from website

Tags: website, telephone, shoretel

Our company uses these fancy ShoreTel 230 phones. We make many phone calls from our custom built web based contact management system. It would be nice if our employees could click on a phone number from a webpage and have it automatically start dialing the number. (Similar to how iPhone handles this)

Anyone every deploy something like this? I would imagine it would require some kind of background running ShoreTel process to accommodate this.

- 90% of our employees use PC (Windows 7)
- 10% use OS X

Even a PC only solution would be great.

Is this even possible and if so, where should one begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shoretel sells software for this called the Shoretel Web Dialer.  It does exactly what you are asking for.  Whenever a phone number is detected on a web page it highlights it as a URL.  You just click the number and it automatically dials to your phone.

Here is a link to a specification sheet:

[Shoretel Web Dialer Specification Sheet](http://media.shoretel.com/documents/WebDialer.pdf)

Comment: Have you used this software? I am wondering if it will work in Chrome?

Comment: @MichaelIrey It's time to call ... ShoreTel.

Comment: I agree with Michael Hampton.  We use the Salesforce Call Adapter which turns phone numbers in Salesforce into URLs to dial.  The adapter works on IE, Firefox, and Chrome.